# 3D plot from multiple arrays

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

I'm successfully plotting a 2d scatter plot:

```
x = np.asarray(plot_data[0])#time variable
y = np.asarray(plot_data[1])#address variable


fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax1.scatter(x,y, s=1, c=u'b', edgecolor='None',alpha=.75)
ax1.set_xlabel('Time')
ax1.set_ylabel('Address')
ax1.set_title('Memory Accesses')
ax1.plot()
```

I want to add a third dimension as hits/interval and developed this:

```
time_axis= np.arange(60)
address_axis=np.arange(0x80000)
data = np.zeros((60, 0x80000))

for i in range(len(plot_data[0])):
    if (plot_data[0][i]//interval) == 60:
        i = 59
    data[plot_data[0][i]//interval][plot_data[1][i]]+=1
```

I can graph each address slice successfully to see that it has summed the total hits for the given interval but every format I've tried to get a 3D graph to work is unsuccessful. Hoping someone has some insight into how I've formatted my arrays incorrectly.

3D attempt

```
time_axis= np.arange(60)
address_axis=np.arange(0x80000)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')


time_axis, address_axis = np.meshgrid(time_axis, address_axis)
Z = data[time_axis][address_axis]
```

results in memory error

attempt to convert to scatter plot:

```
for i in range(60):
    for j in range(0x80000):
        z_array.append(data[i][j])
        x_array.append(i)
        y_array.append(j)

 x = np.asarray(x_array)
 y = np.asarray(y_array)
 z = np.asarray(z_array)

 fig = plt.figure()
 ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
 ax.scatter(x, y, z)
```

This finishes but the graph never posts and the window has to be terminated.

Comment: Anyone that views this:

Was overthinking the problem. Manually converted the array into bins and then plotted those bins similar to the surface plot examples. Basically the solution is

    `x=range(bin_size)
    y=range(bin_size)

    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)      
    ha.plot_surface(X, Y, data, alpha=.7, cmap=mpl.cm.coolwarm)
    print(np.amax(data))`